# How to use Vector Model in Word2Vec

Tags: java, vector, word2vec

I want to use vector model file in Word2Vec. I found the Deeplearning4j documentations and I tried these codes:

```
WordVectors wordVectors = WordVectorSerializer.loadTxtVectors(new File("words.txt"));
WeightLookupTable weightLookupTable = wordVectors.lookupTable();
Iterator<INDArray> vectors = weightLookupTable.vectors();
double[] wordVector = vectors.getWordVector("myword");
```

But there is no getWordVector method in vectors instance. How can I find this method? Also I tried this:

```
WordVectors wordVectors = WordVectorSerializer.loadTxtVectors(new File("words.txt"));
double[] wordVector = wordVectors.getWordVector("myword");
```

These codes is worked but not true. This method gets all vectors in the file. I want to get specific word's vectors.

What can I do?

Thanx.

Comment: Please join us on Gitter https://gitter.im/deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j and ping @raver119. Thanks!